# Functions on adjacency matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-graph-theory

From Norman Biggs, Algebraic Graph theory 2j, p13:
The adjacency matrix has a spectral decomposition $A = \sum \lambda_aE_a$, where the matrices $E_a$ are idempotent and mutually orthogonal.  (...) It follows that if $f$ is any function for which $f(A)$ is defined, then 
$$ f(A) = \sum f(\lambda_a) E_a$$

I can't see how to show this last statement.  It looks to me that we might need to show that $A$ and $f(A)$ have the same eigenspaces, but I can't see even how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A$ is symmetric we can write it as $A= PDP^{T}$ then $f(A) = P\,f(D) \, P^{T}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with $D_{ii} = \lambda_{ii}$ and $P$ is the matrix with columns corresponding to the eigenvectors of $A$ such that $P = (v_1, \ldots ,v_{n})$. A quick multiplication can show that

\begin{equation}
A = PDP^{T} = \lambda_1 v^{T}_1v_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n v^{T}_n v_n.
\end{equation}

similarly
\begin{equation}
f(A) = P\,f(D)\,P^{T} = f(\lambda_1) v^{T}_1v_1 + \ldots + f(\lambda_n) v^{T}_n v_n.
\end{equation}

Clearly, the matrices $E_i= v^{T}_i v_{i}$ are idempotent and mutually orthogonal. A very instructive example to follow is the adjacency matrix of the line between two vertices.

Comment: Ok, I suppose I'm still a bit confused by the step $A = PDP^T \implies f(A) = Pf(D)P^T$.  The text is unclear about how the function $f$ is defined; do they mean it to defined as a function on the algebra of the adjacency matrix $\mathscr{A}(\Gamma) \to \mathscr{A}(\Gamma)$, in which case does this identity $f(A) = Pf(D)P^T$ always hold, or have you just defined the function $f$ as such?

Comment: The function $f$ can be any real function. The key thing here is that $A$ is symmetric and hence has spectral decomposition that allowed us to uplift the definition of the function from scalar to matrix domain. For more general matrices other approaches are also known, see the Wikipedia article:  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function